# Ether transaction

Tags: transactions, ether, myetherwallet

I want email notification whenever any transaction happened in my ether wallet. Is it possible?
Is opt verification possible for any type of outgoing transaction from my ether wallet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the notification system on etherscan.io:

If you have telegram, etherscan.io lets you subscribe to their robot and register your address and receive notification for any transaction to your account.

If you want emails for this:

1. Create an account on https://etherscan.io and/or log in
2. Go to https://etherscan.io/myaddress
3. Click `Add New Address`
4. Enter the address you want to track
5. Select `Email Notification`
6. Click `Continue`

You should now receive email notifications.

Please note that there is a limit of 100 emails/day.